# Powershell - Exchange JSON output without needing to write to a file

Tags: powershell

EDIT:  Added Setupconfigfiles.ps1

I'm a bit new to detailed scripting so please bear with me.
I have two Powershell scripts
Setupconfigfiles.ps1 generates JSON output to be fed to an API.
Script2 uses that JSON data to execute API commands.

Script 2 can call setupconfigfiles.ps1 as indicated below and use the output data.

```
    .\SetupConfigFiles.ps1 -type $Type -outfile .\Templist.json
    $servers = Get-Content -Raw -Path .\templist.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

setupconfigfiles.ps1:

```
param (
    # If this parameter is set, format the output as csv.
    # If this parameter is not set, just return the output so that the calling program can use the info
    [string]$outfile,
    # this parameter can be 'production', 'development' or 'all'
    [string]$type
)

enum MachineTypes {
   production = 1
   development = 2
   all = 3 
}

$Servers = Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "computer"' -SearchBase 'Obfuscated DSN' | Select-Object Name 

$output = @()
$count = 0

# Set this to [MachineTypes]::production or [MachineTypes]::development or [MachineTypes]::all
if ($type -eq "all") {
     $server_types = [MachineTypes]::all
}
ElseIf ($type -eq "production") {
     $server_types = [MachineTypes]::production
}
else {
     $server_types = [MachineTypes]::development
}


ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
   $count = $count + 1  
   $this_server = @{}
   $this_server.hostname = $Server.Name 
   $this_server.id = $count
   $this_server."site code" = $this_server.hostname.substring(1,3)
   $this_server."location code" = $this_server.hostname.substring(4,2)
   if ($this_server.hostname.substring(7,1) -eq "P") {
        $this_server.environment = "Production"
   }
   ElseIf ($this_server.hostname.substring(7,1) -eq "D") {
        $this_server.environment = "Development"
   }
   Else {
        $this_server.environment = "Unknown"
   }

   if (($server_types -eq [MachineTypes]::production ) -and ($this_server.environment -eq "Production")) {
        $output += $this_server
   }
   ElseIf (($server_types -eq [MachineTypes]::development ) -and ($this_server.environment -eq "Development")) {
        $output += $this_server
   }
   Else {
     if ($server_types -eq [MachineTypes]::all ) {
          $output += $this_server
   }
 }
}


if ($outfile -eq "")
{
     ConvertTo-Json $output 
}
else {
     ConvertTo-Json $output | Out-File $outfile
}
```

How can I do it without needing to write to the Templist.json file?

I've called this many different ways.  The one I thought would work is .\SetupConfigFiles.ps1 $servers

Comment: We don't know what `SetupConfigFiles.ps1` is so can't help without seeing it

Comment: `SetupConfigFiles.ps1` should simply write objects to success stream, without conversion to JSON. Then script2 can use that data directly, e. g. `$servers = .\SetupConfigFiles.ps1`

Comment: Then you should show us your `SetupConfigFiles.ps1` because now it seems that it can only output a json string to a given file path. Should be easy enough to change that so it outputs the json directly to the caller

Comment: Sorry about that.  Added the script generating.  This does output to the console as well so I assumed that $servers = .\Setupconfigfiles.ps1 would work but it doesn't.

Comment: @BrianMaxwell looks like you can just supply an empty string to `-outfile` (or omit it completely) and it'll spit the json out as normal output. `$servers = .\SetupConfigFiles.ps1 -type $Type |ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: you try using `-Compress` to make your JSON string one line? should make passing+parsing easier. Saying "would work but it doesn't" doesn't tell us what failed

Answer (score 0):

Y'all are great.  @Zett42 pointed me in a direction and @Mathias rounded it out.

The solution was to change:
"ConvertTo-Json $output"  to "Write-Output $output"

Then it's handled in the calling script.

thanks!